# Feature-detect CSS filter not working

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to detect if the browser supports filters via the @supports rule. @supports seems to work for many cases, however, when I try it on filter property it always returns fail on Chrome, even though it does support filters, in particular: blur.

Check out this demo: http://jsbin.com/gikiwode/1/

I've tried several syntax, `@supports not (filter:blur)`, `@supports not (filter:blur(12px))`, but no case...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to include `-webkit-` prefix?

```
@supports (-webkit-filter: blur()){
  body:before{
    content: 'Can do filters.';
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s2k9T/1/)

Comment: That actually makes sense, since Webkit still needs the browser prefix to do filters. Thanks!